# Xcode 4 distribution build VS Xcode 3 distribution build

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, build, itunes

I'm able to do a distribution build using xcode 3.4 but in Xcode 4.2 I keep getting the error:
*The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.*

I have a valid distribution certificate in the key chain and can get my app in iTunes Connect fine using Xcode 3.2 so I dont get it.

Is Xcode 4 having a hard time finding my distribution certificate and if so how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the profile visible in the organiser window in Xcode 4, and definitely selected against the build settings you are using? You may need to re-import the profiles into Xcode 4, I don't think they are migrated when the new version is installed.

To see what schemes / build settings are in use, go to Product -> Edit Schemes. This will have a list of your different schemes and the build configuration attached to each one. Check what your Archive scheme has for a build setting.

Now, select your project at the top of the navigator on the left hand side. You'll have two tabs in the middle, Info and Build Settings. In Build Settings, scroll down to Code Signing, and under Code Signing Identity for the build setting you are using for Archive, check that it is using the correct profile.

Comment: Hi Yes I've added the profile again to xcode 4 and it is visible. I may not be building agains the correct settings. I'm selecting "Archive" and expecting this to use my "distribution" settings that contains my distribution profile. In xcode 3 you could choose the build configuration but I'm not clear how to do this in Xcode 4.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the answer, hope this helps. I struggled with this myself when I moved to Xcode 4.